# Non-destructive upgrade from Windows 10 Pro to Windows 10 Enterprise?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I'm currently running Win10 Pro and I'm looking to upgrade to Win10 Enterprise (to get rid of Windows bloatware and telemetry etc). Is it possible to install Enterprise while keeping my installed programs? I'm not worried about my files as I have them on a separate drive. I'm just worried about registry stuff because I really want to avoid the hassle of reinstalling and reactivating all my software. I've recently discovered Win10 Education but a) I'm not sure if I can keep it forever, and b) it doesn't include Cortana and I'm not sure if the taskbar search bar is part of Cortana because if it is I don't want to lose it because I use it a lot.

Recap: I'm on Win10 Pro, I want Win10 Enterprise but without losing my programs. Win10 Education is an option but I'm not sure if a) there is a time limit and b) if it removes the search bar at the bottom.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Windows 10 upgrade paths... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/deploy/windows-10-upgrade-paths

Comment: Windows 10 upgrade paths..: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/deploy/windows-10-upgrade-paths just mount the disk and run the installer.  If you want your programs and personal files, select "keep everything" or whatever the choice actually says.

Comment: Win10 Education does not have a time limit, its a VLK product, just like Windows 10 Enterprise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have Windows 10 Pro, you can just change the key to your Windows 10 Enterprise key and you should be done.

You can change the key by either heading to System -> Change Product Key:

[image]

or by running `changepk.exe`.

[More info](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2015/11/23/how-to-convert-windows-10-pro-to-windows-10-enterprise-using-icd/)

---

In the latest versions of Windows 10 this can be found by going to **Settings** -> **Update & Security** and then **Activation**

[image]